# Capture all output, error, warning and their appearance order of linux's command

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

In linux we can redirect stdout and stderr or both of them to files. For example:

- Redirect stdout and stderr to two files: `command 1>out 2>err`. By this way, we can separate output and error in two difference files.
- Redirect both stdout and stderr to files: `command &>all`. By this way, we can capture the appearance orders of output and error message.

I want to combine the two above command: `command 1>out 2>err &>all`, to capture the appearance order of output and error, and separate output and error. But the above command does not work, the `out` and `err` files are empty. If I reverse the order, the `all` file will be empty.
So, is there anyway to combine the two command above as I want?

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` it's a bit tricky:

```
command 2> >(tee err) 1> >(tee out) | tee >all
```

Here we need [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) `>(...)` and `tee` to work around the problem. With process substitution the `tee` process is attachted to the corresponding channel. `tee` then writes the lines into the file *and* prints then to the `STDOUT`. So after writing to the files, both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` will be printed to `STDOUT`. In `bash`, we cannot use multiple redirections of the same chanel in one command. That's why we need to pipe that output to `tee` again, which then just prints it.

---

Within `zsh` (notice the option `MULTIOS` must be set, which is detault in `zsh`):

```
command >out 2>err &>all
```

Comment: you can use one less tee (assuming you didnt want to see the output anyway) with ` 3>all 1> >(tee out >&3) 2> >(tee err >&3)`

Comment: @meuh Ah, good idea over another file descriptor.

Comment: Note that this does not preserve the order of messages to stdout and stderr in the joint output file (`all`), because the intermediate calls to `tee` proceed at their own pace.

Comment: @meuh Magic code! If you are availabe,could you help to make some specification for it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377408/how-to-understand-this-command)?